# alter all tables set default value to null

Tags: mysql, laravel

Due to old migrations in our old laravel application, many `$table->timestamps();` have default values of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Due to our new mysql version, which doesn't allow such dates as default value for timestamps, we have to **alter all tables** to set the default value of the `created_at` and `updated_at` column of all tables to `NULL`

---

How in Laravel could we accomplish this in a migration file?

- A way to loop through all tables and check if there is a `created_at` and `updated_at` column and set their default values to `NULL` or set the timestamps to nullable?
- Loop through all the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns and set their values to `NOW()`

Can anyone assist me with this? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (Before changing a column, be sure to add the `doctrine/dbal` dependency to your  `composer.json` file.):

```
$tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES'); // returns an array of tables
foreach($tables as $table) {
    Schema::table($table, function ($t) {
        $t->nullableTimestamp('created_at')->change();
        $t->nullableTimestamp('updated_at')->change();
    });
}
```

Comment: What classes do I need to import at the top of the migration?

Comment: I think only DB

Comment: It gives me an error that nullableTimestamp() is not a function, which makes sense since in Blueprint theres online a nullableTimestamps()

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#modifying-columns

You can generate new migrations like `update_users_table` in order to put in the `up` method the `nullableTimestamps` method on the $table like this:

```
Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
    $table->nullableTimestamps()->useCurrent()->change();
});
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

MySQL Dates

Starting with MySQL 5.7, 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is no longer considered a valid date, since strict mode is enabled by default. All timestamp columns should receive a valid default value when you insert records into your database. You may use the useCurrent method in your migrations to default the timestamp columns to the current timestamps, or you may make the timestamps  nullable to allow null values:

```
$table->timestamp('foo')->nullable();

$table->timestamp('foo')->useCurrent();

$table->nullableTimestamps();
```

Comment: You can't change nullableTimestamps columns